# remote Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, remote-desktop, remote, windows-command-prompt

I am connecting from my pc1 to Windows server via Widows Remote Desktop Client. Then I execute one application (it has maximized window, and must stay maximized) on remote computer via his own terminal command line.

But what I need now is, to be able to see outputs in that command line window (terminal) - but I can't minimize running application. **How can I see it remotely?**

P.S. (when I am running this application on my own computer, I am using two displays, in first display is maximized app, in second display I see command line window)

**UPDATE:**
sorry friends, I forgot to write, that there can be no other window over maximized window (that app is custom made software, and it doesn't like other windows in front of it).  So I can't simply leave maximized window of that app and open terminal window in front it.

Comment: Could you use the keyboard shortcut Alt+PgUp repeatedly to bring Command Prompt upfront while keeping your other application maximized? This shortcut is the equivalent of Alt-Tab but it is meant for Remote Desktop Connection that are not full screen.

Comment: "That app is custom made software, and it doesn't like other windows in front of it"... WTF?!?

Answer (score 0):

You've not given a whole lot of info, but here try this:

1. Go to your remote computer on remote desktop
2. Instead of whatever icon you are using find out it's command line. (right click on the icon and choose properties.  Get the full command line, i.e. `c:\program files\program\program name` (obviously you fill it in with your stuff)
3. start this command line with a (at the black dos prompt) with 
   start `c:\program files\program\program name` and see if it starts
   You're firing off the program in a command window, you might see output.

This would be more productive if we knew the name of the program.